# Counter reading and writing to a txt file - vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have a script as a counter subscribing to the file C:\tmp\yourtextfile.txt:

```
Set myFSO = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Licznik_ID = myFSO.OpenTextFile ("C:\tmp\yourtextfile.txt"). ReadAll
Licznik_ID + 1 = Licznik_ID
myFSO.OpenTextFile ( "C:\tmp\yourtextfile.txt", 2, True) .write (Licznik_ID)
```

how to do that instead of counting the counter in such a way:

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
e.t.c.

the Counter in the following way to read and save the file to C:\tmp\yourtextfile.txt?

00000001
00000002
00000003
00000004
00000005
00000006
00000007
00000008
00000009
00000010
00000011
e.t.c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first read the text, get the last part with split, convert it to a number, add 1, concatanate that that tot the string and write to the file.
Here your adapted script

```
Function PadZeros(s, l)
  PadZeros = Right("00000000" & s, l)
End Function

Dim myFSO, Licznik_ID, txt, arr
Set myFSO = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
txt = myFSO.OpenTextFile ("C:\tmp\yourtextfile.txt").ReadAll
arr = split(txt, " ")
Licznik_ID = arr(UBound(arr))
txt = txt & " " & PadZeros(CInt(Licznik_ID)+1, 8)
myFSO.OpenTextFile ("C:\tmp\yourtextfile.txt", 2, True).write (txt)
```

As an extra: since I'm switched to Ruby here the equivalent in that language to show you the power of Ruby

```
filename = "C:/tmp/yourtextfile.txt"

txt = File.read(filename)
txt += " %08d" % ((txt.split.last.to_i)+1).to_s
File.write(filename, txt)
```

or as a single line

```
File.read(filename).tap {|txt| File.write(filename, txt + " %08d" % ((txt.split.last.to_i)+1))}
```

It's pretty much explaining itself, the %08d is a formatting template for the string which takes the number and adds until 8 leading zero's, the tap method enumerates the object, in this case the last line of the file

Comment: Using `Right` function isn't the right approach for this case because it will generate a wrong result for any number with `l + n` digits, where `n > 0`.

Comment: @Genius, there are alternatives eg using the String method, but in this use case right is enough, shorter and faster, your approach can be tricked also

Comment: Hello. Nicely counts. Could we do that each digit counter has been saved, the latter the only one in txt file? so instead of within 00001 00002 00003 it be possible to do this: 00003 or to remember the last digit of the final counting.

Comment: Hello Peter. Nicely counts. Could we do that each digit counter has been saved, the latter the only one in txt file? So instead of within 00001 00002 00003 it be possible to do this: 00003 or to remember the last digit of the final counting.

Comment: sure, you just need to change line 10 to txt = PadZeros(CInt(Licznik_ID)+1, 8)

Comment: Hello Peter. How to do that each counted number was added to the line below the line in a column to create a counter history?

Comment: instead of a space " " add VbCrLf , that is a constant which is a line feed

Answer (score 0):

First of all, have you tested this code? because it shouldn't work..

You should replace this line `Licznik_ID + 1 = Licznik_ID` with `Licznik_ID = Licznik_ID + 1`.

Now, in order to pad the number with leading zeros in vbscript, you'll have to write a function for that. You can use the following code:

```
Function LPad(str, l)
  Dim n : n = 0
  If l > Len(str) Then n = l - Len(str)
  LPad = String(n, "0") & str
End Function

Set myFSO = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Licznik_ID = myFSO.OpenTextFile ("C:\tmp\yourtextfile.txt").ReadAll
Licznik_ID = Licznik_ID + 1
myFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\tmp\yourtextfile.txt", 2, True).write(LPad(Licznik_ID, 8))
```

Where `LPad(Licznik_ID, 8)` adds leading zeros to your number to produce an eight digit number. You can replace `8` with the preferred digit numbers.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: testje2.vbs(9, 1) Runtimefout Microsoft VBScript: Typen komen niet met elkaar overeen: 'Licznik_ID'

Comment: Hello.
nicely counts.
Could we do that each digit counter has been saved, the latter the only one in txt file?

so instead of within 00001 00002 00003

it be possible to do this:

00003

or to remember the last digit of the final counting.

Is it possible to have in addition to writing down instead of to the right in order to create a CSV file?